# A confusion of Jordan Canonical Form

Tags: linear-algebra

Recently I have started to study Jordan Canonical Form.
Let $T:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ be a linear transformation having the characteristics polynomial $f(x)=(x-a)^2 (x-b) $. So we have two possible Jordan forms in which the diagonal entries are in the order $a,a,b$. Assume that $T$ is diagonalizable diagonal entries are in the order $a,b,a$! But it need to coincide with one of Jordan form. Where have I done mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the eigenvalues are $a$ (twice) and $b$ (with $b\neq a$, of course) and if, furthermore, the matrix is diagonalisable, then it has three Jordan canonical forms$$\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0\\0&b&0\\0&0&a\end{pmatrix}\text{, }\begin{pmatrix}a&0&0\\0&a&0\\0&0&b\end{pmatrix}\text{, and }\begin{pmatrix}b&0&0\\0&a&0\\0&0&a\end{pmatrix}.$$So, we have *three* Jordan canonical forms, and not just two.

Comment: Carlos Santos,In this case diagonal matrix is not equal to Jordan form.ie.  Jordan form is not applicable in such T?

Comment: @SubhajitSaha I am sorry. I made a mistake and I have edited my answer.

Comment: ,Don't worry.take time☺

Comment: @SubhajitSaha It's done.

Comment: if "T is diagonalizable " not given ..we then have total 6 Jordan forms?

Comment: @SubhajitSaha You'll have five, not six. The three that I mentioned,$$\begin{pmatrix}a&1&0\\0&a&0\\0&0&b\end{pmatrix}\text{, and }\begin{pmatrix}b&0&0\\0&a&1\\0&0&a\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ohh yes...I just missed it,sry